# Access pointer to matrix column-wise

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

With the following code, I can access the row of a pointer to a matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    const int size = 10;
    float **mat = new float*[size];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        mat[i] = new float[size];
        for (j = 0; j != size; ++j) {
            mat[i][j] = i * size + j;
        }
    }
    float *p = mat[size-1];
    for (i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        std::cout << p[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Is there a way that I can access the column,too?  Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT: Sorry, when my question was mis-understood. What I need is a pointer to a column in the matrix mat. I don't think this is possible, is it?

EDIT2: What I basically need is a pointer so that i can do a cast to:

```
__m128 *m_ptr = (__m128*) p;
```

Every extra iteration needs O(n) which should be avoided since I want to vectorize and speed up the code. Row access is easy and fast. Column access should be possible, too???!

Comment: Isn't that what you do with `mat[size-1]`, accessing column?

Comment: well it really depends on what you call row and column :p

Comment: you can't have a pointer to the other direction (column or row or whatever you all it) because your data in that direction is scattered.

Comment: Thanx. That answers all. So it is really not possible. Shit :( How can I close this question?

Comment: don't close. You can have further suggestions. what kind of operations are you going to do with your `__m128` pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to access the elements of a *row* (not column, which is what you are already accessing) that should be simple:

```
for (i = 0; i != size; ++i)
{
     std::cout << mat[i][size - 1] << " ";
}
```

Btw, your code is leaking, because you allocate memory that you never release.

Comment: Well, I do not want to print it, but so safe the column in an array or pointer. Sorry, my question wasn't asked well

Comment: @sdir: If you want to save it into a separate array, just iterate over all elements like I've done above and, instead of doing `std::cout << ...`, copy them into the array. You can't get a pointer to a contiguous array without copying each element separately, because those elements are not stored in contiguous locations of memory.

Answer (score -1):

Elements in a column are not guaranteed to be one after the other in memory...